# two different subjects use one table

Tags: database-design

I'm building a program where a registerd user can book apartments and / or put reservations for restaurants etc. The bookings and reservations come together in one list (this is nog that hard to do).

Now I bumped into a frustrating problem.

You could say I can create two different tables one for bookings and one for reservations, but the data is almost the same except for a booking.

or

You could insert the same data in a table with a fk to the table with more data about the booking? The only problem is each  time you have a reservation the fk is null what I don't like.

Maybe there are some others ways that I don't know yet.
So whats the best option to do?

Answer (score 0):

create another static table which you only store below data.

```
table name:booking type
    id  typename
    1   reservations
    2   booking
```

Now use these ids in another table which have same attributes  to differentiate type.

Comment: I think you mean somthing like EAV?